# How to get Vim to open .git\COMMIT_EDITMSG instead of .git\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG?

Tags: git, vim, git-commit

For some reason, vim keeps trying to open file **COMMIT_EDITMSG** from the wrong path every time. I've been doing multiline commit messages using git-gui cause I was too lazy to fix this problem but I'm getting tired of opening explorer just to commit something. Here's a screengrab that shows what happens when I try to edit a previous commit message:

[image]

And when I try to write the file(note the wrong path):

[image]

It suddenly works when you change the editor to **notepad**:

[image]

**EDIT**:

I've narrowed down the possible causes of the problem to these two settings(after a clean installation and some trial and error):

```
set autochdir
set encoding=utf-8
```

The error can be reproduced with only these two lines your **.vimrc**(at least in mines). The strange thing is that, commenting out one of these statements causes the error to disappear.

Another way to reproduce that error is through these commands:

You should get `".git\COMMIT_EDITMSG" [New DIRECTORY]` with this commmand:

```
vim -N -u NONE --cmd "set autochdir | set encoding=utf-8" .git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

And strangely enough, it should open the file with either of these:

```
vim -N -u NONE --cmd "set autochdir"        .git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
vim -N -u NONE --cmd "set encoding=utf-8"   .git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

Answer (score 0):

Though some stuff indeed is incompatible with `:set autochdir`, the setting is not so malicious that it prevents you from opening any relative paths with Vim. I've been using this for many years without issue. There must be something else (`:autocmd`s?) in your configuration that breaks this (together with `'autochdir'`), because the following works:

```
vim -N -u NONE --cmd "set autochdir" .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

Troubleshooting tip: Often, a *binary search* where you disable half of your plugins, then only one half of that (when the problem is still there), or the other half (when the problem vanished) lets you get to the problematic script quickly. The same can be done with the configuration in your `~/.vimrc` (by commenting out blocks).

Answer (score -1):

**(This answer is not entirely accurate as pointed out in the comments)**

Turns out the problem is this seemingly harmless setting in my **.vimrc**:

```
set autochdir
```

When you try to open a file with a relative path, **Vim** extracts the files parent folder
from the path and switches to that folder. **Git** runs this command(more or less) when you try to amend the previous commit message:

```
vim.exe .git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

But right before opening the file, **Vim** switches to folder **.git** and resolves the full path to the file to something like **C:\mine\.lua\.git\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG** causing the error message with the wrong path.

This anomaly(?) happens with all realtive paths not just those with dots(**'.'**) in them.

[image]

[image]

Not sure if this qualifies as a **Vim** bug...

Comment: According to `:h autochdir` the setting is provided for backwards compatibility and it could break plugins if its turned on. In this case it even breaks external programs that try to use vim.

Comment: This problem seems relatively easy to solve. You just need to prevent the directory change when a relative path is detected. I'm just saying. I don't know anything about Vim development. The problem could be more complicated than it appears.

Comment: This is not accurate; that's not what `autochdir` does. My guess is a plugin you are using does not account for `autochdir`, so disabling it is just a workaround.

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you reproduce it now?